# Is there any way to make front face of gluCylinder() transparent?

Tags: opengl

I am using `gluCylinder()` to create a cylinder in openGL and then plotting points inside the cylinder with Depth Test On .
When i see the front view of the cylinder, the points inside the cylinder are obstructed by front face.

To make front face of the cylinder translucent i am using Blending.

I am using below functions.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

But whatever coloring or alpha value i assign to the cylinder the front face is not looking transparent due to its back face.

Tell whether it is possible to do with blending only or else i need to introduce lighting for both the faces of Cylinder.[Here it clearly visible the change in the color of front face and back face of cylinder. And the points inside the cylinder are not visible due to being obstructed by front face of cylinder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWZVh.png)

Comment: Could you please attach an image? Also maybe you need to draw points first before cylinder.

Comment: Try culling the front faces. it might be the look you want. `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)` and `glCullFace(GL_FRONT)`. Blending might well be the answer but its more complicated than just using a single line. I suggest searching for _additive blending_ its easier and might get the job done.

Comment: @Harish       please tell me the color to be given to the cylinder if i want my front face of the cylinder to be transparent where background is  glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)

Comment: Sorry you can't set selective culling like that. Perhaps use shaders and discard fragments to achieve this? If glClearColor() is white what do you mean by where background is white? Are you reffering to other objects in your scene perhaps behind your cylinder?

Comment: @Unick I have attached the image, now it might be more clear.

Comment: @harish I am talking about the difference in the color i am getting in bottom of cylinder and front face of cylinder. As you can see the bottom is little whitish as compared to front face of cylinder, this is because of blending!

Comment: @subodh Check my answer and try that approach and see if it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to accomplish this by drawing the cylinder twice, while culling the front faces the first time, and culling the back faces the second time. This way, you can draw the front and back parts differently, e.g. by making the front part transparent.

The code sequence could look like this:

```
// Draw back part of cylinder, opaque.
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
gluCylinder(...);

// Draw points.

// Draw front part of cylinder, transparent.
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gluCylinder(...);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: are you sure about this ? because still in the frame buffer the back part is being stored which will affect the blending taking for front part

Comment: Of course you will see the back part through the front part, since the front part is transparent. That's the whole idea. If you don't want the back part at all, just don't draw it by skipping the part of the code above that draws the back. Or draw the back transparent as well, by enabling blending while drawing it just like it's done for the front part.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right then no, you can't do it with blending alone.

If the cylinder's normals all point outward then you also won't be able to see the cylinder's internal parts no matter what you do.

I do something similar to show characters behind walls and it goes like this - render your scene normally and save it all to a framebuffer. Then render what you want shown behind with the buffer contents on top, using a custom shader to make a bubble of transparency around the thing you want shown behind.

Not sure if I am explaining it well or not but it unfortunately requires multiple steps to get the results you want.

Comment: It sounds like it may work... please elaborate the third para or give some link to study if u can...!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is still a bit unclear to me despite the image but I will attempt to answer based on my perception of your issue.

You are drawing a cylinder and have geometry (lines or other models) inside the cylinder. You want the cylinder to look translucent so the inner objects are visible. Here is one way to do it. Assuming your render functions are `drawCylinder()` and `drawPoints()`.

```
init()
{
 ...
 glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
 ...
}

drawScene()
{
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
drawCylinder();
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
drawPoints();
}
```

doing so will make sure that the points are drawn regardless of the cylinder. Try using lower values of alpha for your cylinder color.

Please note this is one way to do it. I suggest using shaders to have more control over blending as well as exploring fragment/pixel discard options.